# Detectar face em tempo real sem colocar o video da camera na tela

Tags: android, android-camera

Olá, sou novo aqui, portanto caso faça algo fora do padrão, peço desculpa antecipada =D

Estou desenvolvendo um aplicativo para fins acadêmicos cujo objetivo é melhorar a postura do usuário durante o uso do Smartphone. Para isto, uso o acelerômetro para detectar a inclinação do telefone e inferir se o usuário está ou não com a cabeça inclinada para usar seu telefone.

Preciso fazer um upgrade para garantir que o usuário está usando o smartphone para não dar falsos alertas, por exemplo: O telefone está ligado em cima da mesa, mas, não tem ninguem necessáriamente usando. A principio se pudesse fazer um reconhecimento facial de tempo em tempo para sabe se tem alguem usando ou não o telefone resolveria meu problema.

Detalhe: O app roda em segundo plano então não posso trazer a camera na frente da tela toda hora, teria que usar sem que o usuário perceba.

Sabem me dizer se isto é possível? Se sim, tem exemplo da aplicação ou algum tutorial para implementar?

Muito Obrigado!

Comment: "fotografar" sem mostrar a tela da Câmera é possível sim. Difícil será você analisar a imagem para concluir se estão usando ou não.

Comment: Inicialmente precisaria apenas detectar se tem uma face ali ou não... Teria algum exemplo?

Comment: Veja isso: https://cloud.google.com/vision/?utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=2016-q1-cloud-latam-ML-skws-freetrial